# Getting error in flutter on rining my app like this

Tags: flutter

**I am unable to run my flutter app please help me to solve this **

```
e: D:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\intent-1.4.0\android\src\main\kotlin\io\github\itzmeanjan\intent\IntentPlugin.kt: (50, 71): Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type Intent?
```

e: D:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\intent-1.4.0\android\src\main\kotlin\io\github\itzmeanjan\intent\IntentPlugin.kt: (55, 39): Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type Intent?
e: D:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\intent-1.4.0\android\src\main\kotlin\io\github\itzmeanjan\intent\IntentPlugin.kt: (56, 69): Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type Intent?
e: D:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\intent-1.4.0\android\src\main\kotlin\io\github\itzmeanjan\intent\IntentPlugin.kt: (58, 67): Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type Intent?

Answer (score 0):

You told compiler that your variable can be null (and assigned null to it).

it seeems plugin issue you can change it by your self
chnage in path **D:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\intent-1.4.0\android\src\main\kotlin\io\github\itzmeanjan\intent\IntentPlugin.kt:**

Comment: Thanks for the responser should i edit the denoted file D:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\intent-1.4.0\android\src\main\kotlin\io\github\itzmeanjan\intent\IntentPlugin.kt

Comment: ya sure you can edit
And also create issue in repo of that plugin so they will also solve this isse.

Comment: But for that i think its about editing a build in flutter files

Comment: Or its is specifically with an added file

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution of this problem by removing intent plugin that i have add using flutter pub add intent , I guesss this might be the issue from the side of PLUGIN AUTHOR or plugin may be outdated .